# Why is QGIS only one label rendering at a time?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, labeling, rendering

I'm new to QGIS, but I'm experiencing what I think is a bug.

When I load the [qgis_sample_data](http://qgis.org/downloads/data/) landcover raster and lakes vector layers, then enable labels for NAMES on that layer, I can only ever view one label at a time.

I've disabled simplified geometry and enabled "show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels) still to no avail.

I've attached [an imgur album of screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7DHT.jpg) to demonstrate the problem - the only thing I'm changing in those screenshots is the zoom level or pan.

Using QGIS 2.8.3 for Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Does it work with only the lakes vector in your project?

Comment: You certainly have something odd going on. I've not used this sample data so I just tried. I'm on Windows 7 with QGIS 2.8.1 I opened QGIS afresh. Then I opened lakes.shp. Under the Lakes layer's properties I choose the labelling options, and checked the checkbox for labelling, with 'NAMES' as where it gets its labels from. Immediately I see labels on every lake.

Answer (score 5):

Check whether you accidentally set a limit on how many features might be labelled. There's a check box under the layer properties | labels | Rendering. It reads "Limit the number of features to be labelled to". See the image:
[image: Labelling options on QGIS]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with QGIS 3.16.1-Hannover, where QGIS was only rendering one label at a time. When I panned or zoomed the view with the label off screen, another feature would get labelled instead.

Following the solutions on this page, as well as on [Labels are not appearing at certain scales](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277119) did not solve it for me.

It turns out it was not a *rendering* issue, but a *data source* issue. The layer source was a database and the unique value column was incorrect.

I solved this by:

1. Right-click on layer > "Update SQL Layer..."

[image: Update SQL Layer]

2. In DB Manager - "Column(s) with unique values": select a column which has unique values. In my case a column was selected which was mostly the same value and that seemed to be causing only one label to appear.

[image: DB unique values column]

3. Click "Update" and close the window

Comment: @Rocky_K you can include the version of QGIS you used.

Comment: @mapperx: Thanks. I've edited the answer to mention that I used QGIS 3.16.1-Hannover.

Comment: The layer used by the OP is not an SQL layer, so your suggestion doesn't apply to its issue.